# Why can't I call insert on a QMap like this?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qmap

Attempting to compile the following code under Qt SDK 4.7.4 for Desktop - MinGW 4.4 results in the compiler error below:

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QMap>
struct Buffer
{
   char data[4];
};
// A Bucket needs to reserve 16 chars worth of Buffers
typedef Buffer Bucket[(16 * (sizeof (char))) / (sizeof (Buffer))];
typedef QMap<QString, Bucket *> BucketMap;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   BucketMap bucket;
   bucket.insert(QString("foo"), new Bucket()); //compile error
   return 0;
}
```

```
../test/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
../test/main.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to 'QMap<QString, Buffer (*)[4]>::insert(QString, Buffer*)'
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/include/QtCore/qmap.h:556: note: candidates are: QMap<Key, T>::iterator QMap<Key, T>::insert(const Key&, const T&) [with Key = QString, T = Buffer (*)[4]]
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
```

I have tried converting this to an quivalent example using `std::string` and `std::map` to the same effect. I have presented the Qt version because it is more compact and ultimately the form that my project requires.
I'm guessing that I am simply missing something about how the `typedef` is ultimately interpreted. Why is the second argument to [`insert`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmap.html#insert) apparently a `Buffer *` (not `Buffer(*)[4]`), and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why use the typedef? Why not create a new Bucket class?  Seems like you're trying to use it as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: The types don't match.

What you actually need to know: You cannot invoke a `new` expression for an array type. Therefore, the following two are not equivalent (and the first isn't legal):

```
typedef T TArr[4]; TArr * p = new TArr;  // #1

T * q = new T[4];                        // #2
```

The language just doesn't work that way. The second version creates a dynamic array, while the first version would like to create a single dynamic object of type "array of 4 T", which is not possible. Instead, `new TArr` is actually the same as `new T[4]`, and so the result is a dynamic *array* of four `T`s.*

You should basically just change your map's value type to either `Buffer *` or `std::array<Buffer, 4> *` or `std::unique_ptr<Buffer[]>` or `std::unique_ptr<std::array<Buffer, 4>>`, whichever you prefer.

<sub>*) This is exactly the reason why the following code is very problematic: `template <T> void foo() { T * p = new T; delete p; }` Imagine you say `foo<int[4]>();`...</sub>

Comment: But if `Buffer` is (basically) `Bucket[16]` and you can do `new Bucket[16]`, then why can't you do `new Buffer`?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You can (edited), but you don't get what you think. You only get the pointer to the basic type, and a dynamic *array*. There's no monolithic single type "array-of-T" that can be created dynamically via (non-array) `new`.

Comment: It just seems weird because `#define TArr T[4] (newline) T* blah = new TArr;` would work properly but `typedef T TArr[4]; T* blah = new TArr;` doesn't

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Changing the line to `typedef std::array<Buffer, (16 * (sizeof (char))) / (sizeof (Buffer))> Bucket;` corrects the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `typedef`. Try the following:

```
int bs = sizeof(new Bucket);
```

and you will see that the value of `bs` is 4 (`INT_PTR`);